# Simple network-programming program - not working

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, network-programming

I just began learning network programming. My first program is very simple: once connected, the server program displays what the client program sends (characters). Everything works fine until they get connected. At first, I did the sending loop using putc:

```
while((c = getc(stdin)) != '\n')
    putc(c, (FILE *) connection);
```

and the receiving one with getc:

```
while((c = getc((FILE *) connection)) != '\n')
    putc(c, stdout);
```

Once connected, I get a segmentation fault. Then I tried using send:

```
while(1) {
    memset(str, null, strlen(memset));

    while(((c = getc(stdin)) != '\n') && sizeof(str) <= 100) {
        strcat(str, (char *) c);       // cast to char * is to make gcc happy
    }

    send(connection, (void *) str, sizeof(str), (int) NULL);
}
```

and recv:

```
while((stat = recv(connection,str,100,0)) != 0) {
    printf("\nReceived %d bytes of data from %s: %s", stat, client, str);
}
```

Now recv() keeps returning -1 and errno is set to 107. What does this mean? Where am I doing wrong? By the way I'm using Linux with gcc.

Thanks a lot for your help! :)

---

**EDIT:** Even if I used getc() and putc(), I get connection with socket(), then I connect() (client). The server, after obtaining connection (with socket()) bind()s, then listen()s and accept()s. Sorry if I ometted.

---

Here's the server code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>

void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct addrinfo hint;
    struct addrinfo *servinfo, *count;
    struct sockaddr_storage conn_addr;
    struct sockaddr host;

    int connessione;
    int stat;
    int conn_sock;
    int conn_size;
    int success;
    int c;

    char t[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
    char str[100];
    char *client;

    if(argc != 1 && strcmp(argv[1], "aiuto") == 0) {
        printf("%s(porta)\n",argv[0]);
        printf("porta: specifica su quale porta installarsi\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    memset(&hint,0,sizeof hint);


    hint.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hint.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hint.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    if((stat = getaddrinfo(NULL, argv[1], &hint, &servinfo)) != 0)  {
        printf("\n[FATAL]: getaddrinfo: %s",gai_strerror(stat));
        exit(-1);
    }

    success = 0;

    for(count = servinfo; count != NULL; count = count->ai_next) {
        if((connessione = socket(count->ai_family, count->ai_socktype, count->ai_protocol)) <= 0)
            continue;

        if((stat = bind(connessione, count->ai_addr, count->ai_addrlen)) == 0) {
            success = 1;
            break;
        }
        else {
            continue;
        }
    }

    if(success == 0) {
        printf("\n[FATAL]: Unable to bind()!\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    else {
        printf("\n[DEBUG]: %s: listening...", argv[0]);
    }

    servinfo = count;
    freeaddrinfo(count);

    if(listen(connessione, 20) == -1) {
        printf("\n[FATAL]: listen: %s (%d)\n", gai_strerror(errno), errno);
        close(connessione);
        exit(-1);
    }

    conn_size = sizeof(conn_addr);

    if(accept(connessione, (struct sockaddr *) &conn_addr, &conn_size) == -1) {
        printf("\n[FATAL]: accept: %s", gai_strerror(errno));
        close(connessione);
        exit(-1);
    }

    client = (char *) malloc(INET_ADDRSTRLEN * sizeof(char));
    client = inet_ntop(servinfo->ai_family, &conn_addr, t, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);

    printf("\n[DEBUG]: %s: connection accepted: %s", argv[0], client);

    while((stat = recv(connessione,str,100,0)) != 0) {
        printf("\nReceived %d bytes of data from %s: %s", stat,client, str);
    }

    printf("\n[DEBUG]: connection closed by %s\n",client);
}
```

And the client's code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>

void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct addrinfo hint;
    struct addrinfo *servinfo, *count;
    struct sockaddr_storage conn_addr;
    struct sockaddr host;

    int connessione;
    int stat;
    int conn_sock;
    int conn_size;
    int success;
    int c;

    char t[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
    char *indirizzo;
    char str[100];

    memset(&hint,0,sizeof hint);

    host.sa_family = AF_INET;
    if(inet_pton(host.sa_family, argv[1], (void *) host.sa_data) == -1) {
        printf("\n[FATAL]: pton: %s (%d)\n", gai_strerror(errno), errno);
        exit(-1);
    }

    hint.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hint.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hint.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
    hint.ai_addr = &host;

    if((stat = getaddrinfo(argv[1], argv[2], &hint, &servinfo)) != 0)  {
        printf("[FATAL]: getaddrinfo: %s\n",gai_strerror(stat));
        exit(-1);
    }

    success = 0;
    for(count = servinfo; count != NULL; count = count->ai_next) {
        if((connessione = socket(count->ai_family, count->ai_socktype, count->ai_protocol)) == -1)
            continue;

        if(connect(connessione, count->ai_addr, count->ai_addrlen) != -1) {
            success = 1;
            break; 
        }
    }

    if(success == 0) {
        printf("\n[FATAL]: impossibile trovare l'host specificato\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    servinfo = count;
    freeaddrinfo(count);

    indirizzo = (char *) malloc(INET_ADDRSTRLEN * sizeof(char));
    indirizzo = inet_ntop(servinfo->ai_family, &conn_addr, t, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);

    printf("\n[DEBUG]: %s: connesso a: %s\n",argv[0], indirizzo);

    while(1) {
        strcpy(str,"buffer for data to send");

        while(((c = getc(stdin)) != '\n') && sizeof(str) <= 100) {
            strcat(str, (char *) c);
        }

        send(connessione, (void *) str, sizeof(str), (int) NULL);
    }
}
```

---

**At the end...**

It works perfectly! Thanks everyone. :)

Comment: How do you do network programming with functions that expect a file handle?  what is the value of 'connection'?  Essentially, you should be using 'socket/send/recv'.

Comment: 107 on Linux is "ENOTCONN". The code 'getc((FILE *) connection))' looks suspicious: what's the type of 'connection'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally you don't use a `FILE *` handle to do network programming. Rather, you need a socket descriptor returned by the `socket(2)` system call. Once you have it, you can either `connect(2)` it (the client) or `bind(2)` it (the server). The ongoing communication can be performed using `recv(2)` and `send(2)`.

If you really want to use a `FILE *` handle to do network programming, take a look at the `fdopen(3)` library function. It takes a descriptor that could be returned by `socket(2)` and returns a `FILE *` handle that is compatible with `fread` / `fwrite` / `fprintf`.

After posting your full code, the most significant error that I could see was:

`if (accept(connessione, (struct sockaddr *) &conn_addr, &conn_size))`

`accept(2)` returns a socket which you have to use with `recv(2)` / `send(2)`, and you discard it, using the server socket instead.

Comment: Post your code including the initialization calls and that might help us spot something.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest You reading http://beej.us/guide/

This is a very nice guide to socket programming

Comment: and where did you get that from?: putc(c, (FILE *) connection);

Comment: That's mine. I tried with it because I wanted to send a character a time, it looked simpler to me.

Comment: @BlackBear: Do you have a clue what happens when you cast `(FILE *) connection`?

Answer (score 1):

When you use a cast (like `(FILE *) connection`) you're telling the compiler: "trust me, this is the truth".  When you lie to the compiler it believes you.

You have lied to the compiler.  `connection` is not a pointer to a FILE structure.  A segmentation fault is the nicest result you can get, because it tells you something is badly wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You make some programming errors:

1) memset(str, null, strlen(memset));

```
should be : memset( str ,0 ,sizeof(str) ); // if str is declared as char str[100];
```

2) while(((c = getc(stdin)) != '\n') && sizeof(str) <= 100)

```
shhould be : while(((c = getc(stdin)) != '\n') && (strlen(str) <= 100))
```

3) send(connection, (void *) str, sizeof(str), (int) NULL);

```
should be : send(connection, (void *) str, strlen(str), (int) NULL);
```